# Is there a python difflib.get_close_matches("targetString", array) equivalent in Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-3, difflib

Is there a method in Ruby similar to Python's  `difflib.get_close_matches("<target_string>", "[<array_of_strings>]")` method?

Comment: For a given set of strings what's your expected result? Just one word matching? Or whole sentences? Also taking into account word order of similar strings e.g. dates or street addresses? Maybe also considering similarity matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach would be

```
$ gem install amatch
```

```
ruby> require 'amatch'
  ==> true

ruby> "a bee sat on my knee".damerau_levenshtein_similar("a bee sat on my knee")
  ==> 1.0

ruby> "a bee sat on my knee".damerau_levenshtein_similar("a fly sat on my knee")
  ==> 0.85

ruby> "a bee sat on my knee".damerau_levenshtein_similar("a BEE sat on my knee")
  ==> 0.85

ruby> "a bee sat on my knee".damerau_levenshtein_similar("a BEE sat on my knee".downcase)
  ==> 1.0

ruby> "snow".damerau_levenshtein_similar(["flow", "snowmobile", "sonw"])
  ==> [0.5, 0.4, 0.75]
```

###### Also available:

:hamming_similar
:pair_distance_similar
:longest_subsequence_similar
:levenshtein_similar
:longest_substring_similar
:jaro_similar
:jarowinkler_similar

Comment: Nice. This is what I was looking for. There is also a gem named 'string-similarity' that I found which is very similar to 'amatch'.